# javascript inverse of getPointAtLength() to return percentage

Tags: javascript, svg

I am working with a SVG path element as follows and if I have an array with the desired percentage, I can retrieve the exact coordinate at each of those percentages of the path by doing the following.

```js
const circ = document.querySelector('.circ');
const len = circ.getTotalLength();

const pct = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1];
const coordCollector = [];

pct.forEach((a) => {
    coordCollector.push(circ.getPointAtLength(a * len))
})
console.log(coordCollector);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div id="container" class="svg-container"></div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1536 720">
      <rect class="vBoxRect" width="1536" height="720" fill="none" stroke="green"></rect>
      <path class="circ" d="M384,552L440.42738422007744,533.665631459995L475.30142556433475,485.665631459995L475.30142556433475,426.3343685400051L440.42738422007744,378.3343685400051L384,360L327.57261577992256,378.334368540005L292.69857443566525,426.334368540005L292.69857443566525,485.6656314599949L327.57261577992256,533.665631459995L384,552" stroke="red" fill="none"></path>
    </svg>
    <!--d3 script-->
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, if I only have the path and an array of objects with raw coordinates, is it possible to calculate at which percentage of the path, they reside?

To be more precise, if I have an array of objects called `rawCoord`, how can I ask javascript to return an array identical to `const pct = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1];`

```js
const circ = document.querySelector('.circ');
const len = circ.getTotalLength();

//for each of this, how can I ask javascript to return an array
//identical to const pct = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1];
const rawCoord = [
  {
    "x": 384,
    "y": 552   
  },
  {
    "x": 440.4273986816406,
    "y": 533.6656494140625
  },
  {
    "x": 475.3014221191406,
    "y": 485.6656188964844
  },
  {
    "x": 475.3014221191406,
    "y": 426.3343811035156
  },
  {
    "x": 440.4273681640625,
    "y": 378.3343505859375
  },
  {
    "x": 383.9999694824219,
    "y": 360.0000305175781
  },
  {
    "x": 327.5726013183594,
    "y": 378.3343811035156
  },
  {
    "x": 292.6985778808594,
    "y": 426.33441162109375
  },
  {
    "x": 292.6986083984375,
    "y": 485.6656494140625
  },
  {
    "x": 327.5726318359375,
    "y": 533.6656494140625
  },
  {
    "x": 384,
    "y": 552
  }
]
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div id="container" class="svg-container"></div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1536 720">
      <rect class="vBoxRect" width="1536" height="720" fill="none" stroke="green"></rect>
      <path class="circ" d="M384,552L440.42738422007744,533.665631459995L475.30142556433475,485.665631459995L475.30142556433475,426.3343685400051L440.42738422007744,378.3343685400051L384,360L327.57261577992256,378.334368540005L292.69857443566525,426.334368540005L292.69857443566525,485.6656314599949L327.57261577992256,533.665631459995L384,552" stroke="red" fill="none"></path>
    </svg>
    <!--d3 script-->
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Update**

The `rawCoord` will always have the objects in the array with `x,y` coordinates that reside on the path (if the percentage was known beforehand, the same x,y coordinate will yield from `circ.getPointAtLength(percentage * len)` ) but not necessarily part of the path's `d` attribute. It may or may not conatin objects which are part of path's `d` attribute.For example,

```
const rawCoord = [
{"x": 319.5282897949219, "y": 522.5936279296875},
{"x": 475.3014221191406,"y": 426.3343811035156},
{"x": 347.28009033203125, "y": 371.9310302734375},
{"x": 292.6985778808594, "y": 444.60089111328125},
{"x": 436.65045166015625, "y": 377.107177734375},
{"x": 364.9917297363281, "y": 366.1761779785156},
{"x": 327.5726013183594,"y": 378.3343811035156},
{"x": 327.0311279296875, "y": 379.07965087890625},
{"x": 320.73773193359375, "y": 524.2582397460938},
{"x": 450.1088562011719, "y": 520.3402099609375},
{"x": 292.6986083984375,"y": 485.6656494140625},
{"x": 458.6446838378906, "y": 403.4083557128906},
{"x": 301.19525146484375, "y": 497.36029052734375}
]
```

Comment: In your example, the points in the array are the nodes of the path segments. Is that always the case?

Comment: What if the path goes round and round and round? i.e. a single co-ordinate may be at many points on a path.

Comment: The rawCoord array would always contain x,y points that reside on the path segments but I would not know beforehand (unlike in the sample provided @0%,10%,20%...) at which percentage of the path they reside.

Comment: "contain" is not precise enough. Can the array contain points that are not segment nodes? Can there be segment nodes that are not present in the array?

Comment: How are these points generated? Do you have a minimal precision the percentage can be?